# SQL where clause with multiple keys in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has two keys and I cannot break the table up into two.

The first key, id is a counter.  The second key is parent_id.

For example:

id, parent_id, text
1, 0, Hello Steve - this is Bill
2, 1, Hi - how are you Bill?
3, 0, Good morning Janice
4, 3, Hello - good morning to you

The first record is the parent record of the conversation and the second is the child record.

What I'm having difficulty doing is writing a query that returns both records for a single conversation when you pass either id.

For example:

```
select * from table where id = 2 or parent_id = ( select parent_id from table where id = 2 )
select * from table where id = 1 or parent_id = ( select parent_id from table where id = 1 )
```

The first query will work, returning the records with id 1 and 2.  The second will not as it will return the row with id 3 as well because if you pass 1 you'll get zero for the parent_id.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing due to paralysis by analysis.

Thanks.

Comment: For what database?  You've tagged this as TSQL & MySQL, which are different extensions of SQL.  Also, MySQL doesn't have hierarchical query support...

Comment: Sorry, it's MySQL.  I don't know how that hierarchical-query tag got in there however.

Comment: Actually: from your data set posted above - can you clarify something: What would the record look like for Janice's reply to "4, 3, Hello - good morning to you" ?

Comment: 5, 3, How is your day going Janice?

Comment: OK : so I think a filesystem analogy would be : the original post is like a 'folder' and all replies are like files directly within that folder: but there are no 'sub-folders' allowed: each parent may have many children, but each child cannot have any children of its own.
If that's right - then I *think* a simple 'UNION' should do it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will retrieve:

- the specified child record, its parent, and its siblings
- the specified parent record and all its single-level children

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
 (
    --is a child of the specified parent
    SELECT * from table  WHERE parent_id = @SomeID 
    UNION ALL
    -- is the record specified by ID
    SELECT * from table  WHERE ID = @SomeID 
                         --and get the parent itself
                         OR ID = (SELECT parent_id FROM table WHERE ID = @SomeID) 

    UNION ALL
    --all siblings with the same parent
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent_id = (SELECT parent_id 
                                           FROM table WHERE ID = @SomeID) 
                        AND parent_id>0

   ) F
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: I was thinking this needed a 'UNION' as well...I don't think my answer quite covers though....

Comment: This works.  I wish there was a cleaner way to do it but I can't figure it out and this is a little cleaner than the huge union query I came up with, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add `AND parent_ID <> 0` to your subquery.

Comment: If you do that and pass in the child ID, it omits the parent record and if you pass in a parent ID, it omits the child records.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- I *think* from OP's description , this should do it.
-- The first SELECT will _always_ bring back a single row (the ID is unique and known to the issuer of the query).
-- The second SELECT may bring back zero, one or many rows
-- So (if my understanding is correct) in English:
-- Bring back the row for the given ID and all (if any) rows which have me as a parent_id.
-- Rehashed : joining up the IDs from parent->child
-- Again, not tried...
SELECT * FROM table parent WHERE parent.id = <id>
union
SELECT * FROM table child WHERE child.id=parent.id;
```

Comment: If you want to return the first conversation, records with id 1 and 2, and you pass 1 using the queries in my example, you'll also get 3 back because it has a parent_id of zero as well.

Comment: Understood that (I think) - but is the data-model not going to imply this ? Ultimately do you always want exactly one row returned - or could this vary , depending on the conversation history?

Comment: No, ultimately I want the whole conversation returned whether a child or parent ID is passed into the query.  My mistake not making that clear in the OP.

Comment: So is a 'conversation' exactly one parent and exactly one child ? (always expect/want two rows back?) I guess (also from an earlier posting answer) - that the main issue here could be that '0' is 'special' - it denotes 'start of conversation....would then the '<>0' bit work (suggested above).

If you do need to traverse more than two records, not sure how you would do this without 'CONNECT BY' type arrangements....

Comment: No, there could be many child records.  Think of it as an article commenting system.  One person adds a comment and multiple people can add replies to that comment.  It only goes one deep though, users cannot reply to a reply.  Basically a user can click reply to a parent comment or a child comment and on the comment page they can review the entire thread so whether a parent ID or child ID is passed, I want to return the entire conversation.

Comment: Hi Tom - just commented on your OP - can you add in a couple more examples of what subsequent records would like ...

Comment: Yeah, that query just returns a child record if you pass a child ID into it.  I have a huge union query that works (needs for selects) but there has to be an easier way.

Comment: Just re-hashed that again...still not giving you what you want ? Have you tried P.Cambell's suggestion at all ? (looks like it should do the trick - actually , it beyond my capabilities :-) )

Comment: Yeah, that works.  Wish there was a cleaner way but I'm thinking there isn't...thanks for the help though monojohnny =)

Comment: ( No worries: I know you said you can't change your data model, but probably that would be the 'proper' solution..separating 'post' records and 'reply' records...) anyway - glad you got something that works ! Cheers